# PrimeFaces Warning about filteredValue in datatables not appearing anymore (version 7.0)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hey guys im migrating an application from 3.5 to 7.0, on 3.5 we have this warning whenever we have a datatable on our view (xhtml):

```
WARNING [org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable] (default task-8) DataTable frmAperturaCajaMasiva:dtbFrmCaja has filtering enabled but no filteredValue model reference is defined, for backward compatibility falling back to page viewstate method to keep filteredValue. It is highly suggested to use filtering with a filteredValue model reference as viewstate method is deprecated and will be removed in future.
```

It states that viewstate method is deprecated and will be removed in future, but I haven't done any changes to datatables methods while migrating neither added the filteredValue model reference and the warning dissapiared, im wondering if maybe they changed their mind about this warning or what happened? In the migration guide can't see anything about it https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Migration-Guide

Comment: See showcase example: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml  You need `filteredValue="#{dtFilterView.filteredCars}"` on your datatable to hold the filtered list.

Comment: @Melloware, hmm I could use it but, it is working well without it, so I was thinking on not using it since the warning dissapeared, what do you think??

Comment: You may find erratic behavior without it but yeah go ahead and try without it.

Comment: @Melloware Okay ;p hope it doesn't show any errors